# sql distinct + count

Tags: php, sql

What I want to do is count specific instances of the same column for each user.

example:
`vagt_type` might have the value of "timeloen" 10 times where `usr = 1` and the value of "prov" 2 times for that user.  I need the counts in separate columns and I'm using `DISTINCT` to only get each usr once.

Below is what I've worked out so far but, that counts all the instances of `vagt_type` and for some reason is not affected by the `cast` from date to date:

```
$test = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT distinct m.usr, CONCAT(n1.meta_value, ' ', n2.meta_value) AS fl_name, count(m1.vagt_type) as timeloen
FROM $main_table as m
LEFT JOIN Lausten_usermeta n1 ON m.usr=n1.user_id and n1.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN Lausten_usermeta n2 ON m.usr=n2.user_id and n2.meta_key = 'last_name'
LEFT JOIN $main_table m1 ON m.usr=m1.usr and m1.vagt_type = 'timeloen'
WHERE m.vagtDato BETWEEN CAST('$start' AS DATE) AND CAST('$end' AS DATE)
", ARRAY_A);
```

**Edit:** 
example of my table:

```
 id | usr | vagtDato   |  vagt_type
 13 |   1 | 2015-09-05 |    kursus
 16 |   1 | 2015-09-01 |    kursus
 11 |   1 | 2015-09-03 |    trappetur
 10 |   1 | 2015-09-02 |    provision
 9  |   1 | 2015-09-01 |    timeloen    
 15 |   1 | 2015-09-04 |    sygedag
 17 |   1 | 2015-09-02 |    timeloen    
 18 |   29| 2015-09-18 |    timeloen    
 19 |   1 | 2015-10-01 |    timeloen
```

the other table there is just a `join` to the user table and its not important in this case as I only use it to `CONCAT` the fullname of the user.

Expected results:

```
usr | timeloen | provision | sygedag
1   | 3        | 1         | 1
29  | 1        | 0         | 0
```

EDIT: --
hope this helps someone else :)
What ended up being my total solution:

```
$test = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT a.usr, a.vagtDato, b.timeloen, c.provision, d.kursus, e.trappetur, f.sygedag
FROM $main_table a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as timeloen
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'timeloen'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) b on b.usr=a.usr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as provision
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'provision'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) c on c.usr=a.usr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as kursus
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'kursus'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) d on d.usr=a.usr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as trappetur
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'trappetur'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) e on e.usr=a.usr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as sygedag
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'sygedag'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) f on f.usr=a.usr

WHERE a.vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY a.usr
", ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: We can't help without seeing how your tables relate to each other and some sample data and expected results

Comment: `CAST('$end' AS DATE)` is completely wrong. This is what you should fix first. PDO or mysqli will do that for you if you bind each parameter with the proper data type.

Comment: What you're asking for is sometimes referred to as a pivot. Not all databases support it. Take a look at this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would believe you have to put something like:

```
SELECT
    usr
    , ( SELECT( count( * ) FROM $TABLE where vagt_type = 'timeloen' ) AS timeloen
    , ( SELECT( count( * ) FROM $TABLE where vagt_type = 'provision ' ) AS provision 
    , ( SELECT( count( * ) FROM $TABLE where vagt_type = 'sygedag' ) AS sygedag
FROM ( $main_table )
    ( $LEFTJOINS )
GROUP BY usr --to get the distincts users
```

or

```
SELECT
    usr
    , count( * )
FROM ( $main_table )
    ( $LEFTJOINS )
GROUP BY 1, 2 --to get the distincts users
```

Comment: Or at least its very close the query count for timeloen - provision and such return same result for all users...

Comment: Your welcome..Anytime. Sorry I couldn't do much though because I was on my phone. But still glad I can help